# CAD file hatching in QGIS

Tags: fill, shape-area

I have a CAD file work highway land acquisition plan.
I want to hatch / solid fill in QGIS software, for to get area.
See attached image[image]

This above file in CAD.

What I want see attached image[image]

Comment: You can grab areas in CAD, too. Also, it is unclear, what your problem is.

Comment: Sir I have a shape file, as you see in first image, what I want , i want to hatch or sold fill small small plot by qgis. I need output as per image 2. All hatch must be separated, means each plot have separate hatch. Mainly I need only hatch , area I will get from cad tool. Hope now understand sir

Comment: Yeah, but we don't know, whether you have lines, multilines or polygons. We don't know which version of QGIS you're working with. And we don't know, what you tried so far, because `lines to polygon` is rather straigthforward and obvious.

Comment: 1.All are lines. 2. version 3.20     3. Fill all lines like image 2

Comment: So, did you run `lines to polygon`? If so, how is the output not satisfactory?

Comment: Sir, image 2 with colour hatching, prepared by someone he did not explain me . For information I will upload cad file and shape file here, then upload screen shot how work done by qgis. Either sir provide me your email address, for direct send.thanks.               Outer line is already a close polyline.

Comment: Nope, I wont give my mail address. As I stated twice already, `lines to polygon` is the tool you want to use, once you loaded your data into QGIS.

Comment: @MohdIshrar please do not ask for users email addresses - please use the stack exchange for a communication tool with transparency, there is a chat that can be used rather than comments https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=gis.stackexchange.com if required.